# byte array parameter in visual c++

Tags: windows-phone-8, c++-cx, visual-c++-2012

i am new to visual c++.. I had a method in .h file something like this:

```
  public:
   void DoSomething();
```

Here i need to pass byte array as parameter and i need to implement it in .cpp file.. I am working on windows phone 8 for this i need to include visual c++ project of windows phone run time component. I need to use this method in c# class and pass the byte array from there. But i dont know how to declare a byte array method in c++. can any one please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++/CX, what you're using for a Runtime Component, the signature would look like this (assuming you have a `ref class`):

`void DoSomething(const Platform::Array<uint8>^ something);`

This could be called from C# directly by passing in a `byte[]`.

Comment: hi, it worked fine when i am calling from c# thank you. i want to call "Method1"(for example) method in "C" whose parameter should be byte array.I want to call this method from C++. how to pass the "something" parameter to method in C.

Comment: You should be able to use the Data and Length properties on Array to pass the contents along to some C code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
   void DoSomething(Byte *);
```

Or

```
public:
   void DoSomething(unsigned char *);
```

for exemple.

Comment: thank you for ur answer.it gives only single byte as out paramter. but i need here byte array with ref.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need.
i can say that if you want a reference instead just replace * by & like this : DoSomething(unsigned char &);.

Comment: i would like to use this dosomething method in c# and pass byte array to it.. but when i am accessing this method in c# class it is excepting byte as out parameter but i want it to be byte array as in paramter..

Comment: Well, and does it change something when you declare DoSomething with a reference instead of a pointer like i said in my previous answer ?

Comment: no it throws an error as low level pointers does not work in the native code.

Comment: Maybe the case exposed here will solve your problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/02b3ce75-1a4a-4e3d-bfa2-521829a8e644